# ngStyle directive not applied to a link tag

Tags: angular, ng-style

I'm attempting to style a link to a colour that is generated from an API. This works for text buttons etc, but when I try to apply this to a link it doesn't work.

```
<a href="#" [ngStyle]="{'color': brand?.colours.secondary}" *ngIf="!visitorName" (click)="setVisitor()">Don't want to give your name? That's fine! Start the review!</a>
```

It just gets overridden by the bootstrap link styling.

[image]

Applying this to a 'p' tag works just fine however - so the correct colour code is pulled from the API and loaded in ok:

```
<p class="mt-5" [ngStyle]="{'color': brand?.colours.secondary}">Don't worry we won't use your details for anything other then to give you the best experience possible.</p>
```

Comment: works well for me https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-grothendieck-qcu2j?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Are you sure your typescript version is 3.7 or above. As optional chaining(`?.`) is supported as of 3.7.

Comment: it also worked for me https://angular-ivy-zzn2rj.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ngstyle` , use `attr.style`.

in SomeComponent.ts

```
myColor = fetchColorSomehow(); //#ff55aa or any color
```

in SomeComponent.html

```
[attr.style]="'color:'+mycolor+'!important'"
```

Here we are *overriding* the bootstrap color using **!important**